# Integrating direct line speech into Microsoft Virtual Assistant?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I've been doing a POC for Microsoft Virtual Assistant using their template as a base in c# (found here: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions). I've deployed my code to azure and added and deployed some skills and have been using the application in Bot Framework Emulator to test all successfully.

Now, I want to add a scenario where the user can use the the Virtual Assistant hands-free, using voice. I've been reading that the Direct Line Speech is the way to go for this but have been having some double getting started.

I've created a direct line speech channel in my azure webapp. Then I followed these guides:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-directlinespeech?view=azure-bot-service-4.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/directline-speech-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

I feel like some information is missing since the direct line speech secret isn't mentioned at all in the 'Use Direct Line Speech in your bot' guide.

Anyone with any experience in this would be a major help, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who might search this later, I found my primary issue is was that I was using a webchat implementation that isn't currently supported by the direct line speech preview.

For integrating speech in webchat properly I was able to find a bunch of examples of web chat implementations from Microsoft [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat). Specifically, the two examples that I found most helpful was an implementation of speech [using a the built-in browser methods in this sample solution](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.d.speech-web-browser) and then [using Microsoft Cognitive Services in this solution](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.c.cognitive-services-speech-services-js).